# Convert two's complement to sign-magnitude

Tags: c, twos-complement

I need to convert from two's complement to sign-magnitude in C using only the operators

```
! ~ & ^ | + << >>
```

My approach is to find sign:
`int sign = !(!(a>>31));`

basically, `if sign == 1` . I want to flip the number and add 1 else just want to display the number.

The thing is I can't use any loops, if statements etc.
This is what I'm working on:

```
int s_M = ((((a+1)>>31)^sign)+1)&sign;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use code formatting and backticks to format code for an easier read.

Comment: can u use ternary operator?

Comment: That's the thing, I can't. That's what makes this tricky I have to work with what I've got. I can't either use && or || just & or |

Answer (score 2):

From http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs

```
int const mask = v >> 31;
unsigned int r = (v + mask) ^ mask;
```

Gives the absolute value (magnitude). If you wish to add the sign bit back simply mask and or the 32nd bit:

```
unsigned int s_M = r | (v & 0x80000000);
```

Or if you're looking for a one liner:

```
unsigned int s_M = ((v + (v >> 31)) ^ (v >> 31)) | (v & 0x80000000);
```

Comment: Why `const` in `int const mask = v >> 31;`?

Comment: the thing is if I have the number 0x80000001 it should be converted to -1 instead of -2147483647.

Comment: @chux I took that from the Bit Twiddling Hacks link. By making something const I presume it can maybe help the compiler make certain optimizations, though I really don't know for sure.

Comment: @user2938343 (-1) in 2's complement is 0xFFFFFFFF, not 0x80000001 (-2147483647). If you stick -1 in the converter, you'll get 0x80000001 because the 32nd bit is set (- sign) and your value is 1. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question...

Answer (score 0):

When you're converting **from** 2 complement, you should subtract 1, not add.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the output should be, but to obtain the magnitude you can do something like this:

```
int m = (a^(a>>31)) + sign;
```

Basically, shifting a negative number 31 bits to the right will make it all 1's, or `0xffffffff`, which you can then use to xor the input number and make it positive. As you correctly noted `sign` needs to be added then for the correct result in that case.

If the input number was positive to begin with, the shift results in a zero and so the xor does nothing. Adding `sign` in that case also doesn't do anything, so it results in the input number.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last bit you could use mask operation

```
   int last_bit = 32 bit integer & 0x80000000 
   o/p  may be 0 or 0x80000000
```

if it is `0` just display the given number else you have to perform the following operations to represent in signed magnitude

**1)** Subtract 1 from the number

**2)** perform 1s complement on the resultant ( that is negation `~`)

**3)** Set the last bit of the resultant number

```
 I mean  ( ~ (num -`1) ) | 0x7fffffff
```

since your restricted not to use `-` operator.  Perform the `2's complement on -1` and add it to the `num`.

```
To put it simple in one line
 num & 0x80000000 ? printf("%d",(~(num+((~1)+1))) | 0x7fffffff) : printf("%d",num)   ;
```