# In binary, convert from signed-magnitude to two’s-complement. All in C

Tags: c, puzzle, bit, limits

I have an interesting puzzle. I need to convert from a signed number, say -5 (0x80000005) to two’s complement -5 (0xFFFFFFFB). The only operators I can use are, !, ~, &, ^, |, +, <<, >> and at most 15 of them in any combination with as many variables as I want. = may be used and does not count towards the total number of operators. Also, no “if” statements, loops or calls to functions of any kind may be used.

the function will look like

```
int sign2two(int x){
//... some stuff here
return x;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I can find out if the number is negative. But I want to say, if num is negative then flip bits and add 1. Otherwise return number. And I can’t figure out how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: && is not an operator I am allowed to use.

Comment: Why? Because the CPU you're working for doesn't support that or because hat is a rule of a homework?

Comment: this is how to do just the opposite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689586/convert-twos-complement-to-sign-magnitude , a little effort from your part and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from Sign Magnitude x to Two's Complement y:

1) On a two's complement machine.
2) Uses only !, ~, &, ^, |, +, <<, >>
3) Does not use ?:, -, *, /
4) Does not assume 4-byte int
5) Works with all Sign Magnitude integers including +0 and -0

```
#include <limits.h>
int sm2tc(int x) {
  int sign = x & INT_MIN;
  int negmask = UINT_MAX + !sign;
  return (x & ~negmask) | (negmask & ((~x + 1)^INT_MIN));
}
```

This answer is to a duplicate question [How to convert from sign-magnitude to two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837008/how-to-convert-from-sign-magnitude-to-twos-complement) whose selected answer did not meet the OP's stated criteria considering operation restriction.

Comment: What happens if 0x8000000 is passed in? Your code seems to return  0x80000000.

Comment: @Benb, do you mean `0x8000000` (0x8 + 6 zeros) as in your comment, the code returns `0x8000000` (0x8 + 6 zeros) as it should.  If you mean `0x80000000` (0x8 + 7 zeros), the code returns `0` as it should on a 32-bit `int`. Checked with a re-test.  If you are running on a 64-bit int, then `0x80000000` (0x8 + 7 zeros) should return `0x80000000` (0x8 + 7 zeros).

Comment: I apologize. I made an error in making my UMAX. Thank you, you have earned the chosen solution.

Answer (score 2):

These problems are extremely dumb in my opinion...

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int32_t test1(uint32_t x) {
    const uint32_t sign  = (x & 0x80000000); // Total operations: 1
    const uint32_t value = (x & 0x7FFFFFFF); // Total operations: 2

    // Let's create a value N, where N is equal to:
    // if (sign)
    //     N = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    // else
    //     N = 0x00000000;
    uint32_t N = sign;  // Total operations: 2
    N = N | (N >> 1);   // Total operations: 4 
    N = N | (N >> 2);   // Total operations: 6
    N = N | (N >> 4);   // Total operations: 8
    N = N | (N >> 8);   // Total operations: 10
    N = N | (N >> 16);  // Total operations: 12

    // Let's create a value MaybeOne, where MaybeOne is equal to:
    // if (sign)
    //     MaybeOne = 1;
    // else
    //     MaybeOne = 0;
    uint32_t MaybeOne = N & 0x1; // Total operations: 13

    // Now, Let's perform the following step:
    // if (sign)
    //     return (value ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1;
    // else
    //     return (value ^ 0x00000000) + 0;
    return (value ^ N) + MaybeOne; // Total operations: 15
}

int32_t test2(uint32_t x) {
    int32_t sign = (x & 0x80000000);
    int32_t value = (x & 0x7FFFFFFF);

    if (sign)
        return -value;
    else
        return value;
}

int main() {
    uint32_t i;
    for (i=0; i<0xFFFFFFFF; ++i) 
        if (test1(i) != test2(i))
            printf("0x%08x\n", i);
}
```

---

Additionaly, using a comment from [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil), we can reduce the number of operations significantly:

```
int32_t test3(uint32_t x) {
    const uint32_t sign  = (x >> 31);        // Total operations: 1
    const uint32_t value = (x & 0x7FFFFFFF); // Total operations: 2

    // Let's create a value N, where N is equal to:
    // if (sign)
    //     N = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    // else
    //     N = 0x00000000;
    const uint32_t N = ~sign + 1;  // Total operations: 4

    // Let's create a value MaybeOne, where MaybeOne is equal to:
    // if (sign)
    //     MaybeOne = 1;
    // else
    //     MaybeOne = 0;
    uint32_t MaybeOne = sign; // Total operations: 4

    // Now, Let's perform the following step:
    // if (sign)
    //     return (value ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1;
    // else
    //     return (value ^ 0x00000000) + 0;
    return (value ^ N) + MaybeOne; // Total operations: 6
}
```

Comment: Looking at the second answer, what is the function of MaybeOne? Why can't you just use sign? Also, I didn't mention this but the only variable types that can be used are just regular int.

Comment: In my tester the second answer seems to work until I try 0xffffffff.
I'm getting a return of 0x7ffffffd when it should be 0x80000001.

Comment: On paper it also works out to be 0x7ffffffd. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By hand, `0xFFFF_FFFF == -(0x7FFF_FFFFF)`. So `sign2two(0xFFFFFFFF) == -(2147483647)`. If we were to convert `0x80000001` as a two's complement number to decimal, we would also get `-2147483647`. So the correct operation (which the code above performs) is `test1(0xFFFFFFFF) == 0x80000001`.

Answer (score 2):

You have no conditionals available but you can mask. There are different ways of creating a mask dependent on the value of the sign.

The following uses very nice tips by **Eric Postpischil**!

If the sign is 0 (ie positive) then the mask will become 0, else it is still the value you need -> conditional without conditional

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int sign2two(unsigned int a){
    int sign = a>>31; // alternative: sign = !!((a<<1>>1)+~a+1);  see below
    unsigned int withoutSign = a << 1 >> 1;
    unsigned int mask = ~sign +1;
    printf("withoutSign is: %u\nsign is: %u\nmask is: %x\n", 
        withoutSign, sign, mask);
    unsigned int temp = (withoutSign^mask)+sign;
    return *(int*)&temp;
}
void printSign2two(unsigned int a){
    printf("the 2s complement number: %i\n\n", sign2two(a));
}
int main(){
    printSign2two(0x00000005);
    printSign2two(0x80000005);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
withoutSign is: 5
sign is: 0
mask is: 0
the 2s complement number: 5

withoutSign is: 5
sign is: 1
mask is: ffffffff
the 2s complement number: -5
```

**Note** about the `sign = !!((a<<1>>1)+~a+1);`. This uses some more operators than `sign = a>>31` but it is independent of 32/64 bitness.

- `<<1>>1` clears the most significant bit,
- we then want to check if it is different than the original. since `-a` is not allowed we use `+~a+1` (thanks again **Eric Postpischil**)
- if there is no difference we already have the value 0 we want, else we have some huge number
- we then use !! to change the huge number to 1.

Comment: Technically this is outside the bounds of the question, because Benb is not allowed to use the multiplication operator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil very nice tips! I used them, hope you dont mind. If I were in your place I would have made my own answer. I will try to find something to get rid of the `31`.

Comment: sign = !!((a<<1>>1)-a);

Comment: This is my favorite so far: `unsigned int m = a ^ a<<1>>1, z = !m + ~0u; return a+z ^ z>>1;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil nice. you should make an answer and explain the steps to me and others :-)